# nodejs asynchronous nested requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am new to asynchronous programming and I have seen many examples where you can send many requests in parallel using promises or the async library but not multiple rounds of requests where the request will depend on the previous requests.

The problem:
I am querying a graph-like database, consider:

```
    | node | connected |
    | 1    | 2         |
    | 2    | 3         |
    | 4    | 5         |
```

or in graphical form:

`(1)-(2)-(3)   (4)-(5)`

Based on an input node id (e.g. `1`) I need to extract all the records which can be traced to node `1` (in this example `[1,2,3]`)

I am unsure how to implement this using asynchronous programming.
If function `queryDB` took an id as input and returned a connected id then I could do this:

```
inputID = 1;
nodes = [1];
queryDB(inputID,function(a){
    nodes.push(a);
    queryDB(a,function(b){
        nodes.push(b)
    });
});
```

This would produce `nodes = [1,2,3]`
This obviously will not scale well. I am looking for a better way to implement this so any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Use recursion! It's not really different from a synchronous version.

Comment: Could there be multiple connected nodes? For those, you could use the parallel execution.

Comment: do you mean you don't understand how to execute call flows in parallel? E.g. you have 3 calls that have to be made in sequence, and you have many of those that you'd like to execute in parallel?

Comment: @Kevin - I have many thousand and they all depend on each other so a simple parallel approach wont work.

Comment: @Bergi - Thanks recursion seems to work quite well!